# Extjs multiple instances of treepanel respond to same expand()

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, components, expand, treepanel

I have a rather strange issue to contend with today...

Essentially, I have created a custom component that contains a treepanel.  Within my main application, a user can create a number of these components within different tabs of a tabpanel.

If I expand a node on one instance of this component, it is expanded on all instances (and any subsequently created instances).  All other click listeners, etc remain unique to each instance.

I have checked out the ExtJs source code, and I don't see anything offending in there.  I thought it could have been a clashing itemId, but after randomising them, the issue was still there.

Perhaps it's something to do with them sharing the store?

I can include code in this post, but I don't know how much use it would be.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you put some object-specific settings into class prototype instead of config passed to an object. It's only a guess but if it's right, then one should set **items** and other fields in initComponent, not directly in object passed to Ext.define. Anyway, show your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, if I set my treepanel store using Ext.create(), it works; if I just set it in the config, it uses the same store for all the treepanels.